# How can I query contract info with the latest polkadot-js and substrate contracts node?

Tags: substrate, polkadot-js, rust-ink

I've been unable to query my existing contract recently due to `Unable to create Enum via index 128, in Alive, Tombstone` when using `api.query.contracts.contractInfoOf`. I get this error both on the command line and in the polkadot-js apps explorer.

These are the steps I took:

1. Deploy a contract with a `salt`
2. Retrieve the contract `deployedAddress`
3. Use `contractInfoOf`
4. `const contractInfo = await api.query.contracts.contractInfoOf(deployedAddress);`

I've tried downgrading `ink!` to `3.0-rc5`, `3.0-rc4`, `3.0-rc3` and then compiling but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Whenever my contract is built it references `rc6` at the top:

```
{"metadataVersion":"0.1.0","source":{"hash":"0x...","language":"ink! 3.0.0-rc6","compiler":"rustc 1.58.0-nightly",
```

Which suggests its ignoring my `.toml` and using `rc6` to compile the contract.

I changed my `cargo-contract` version to `0.14` but that causes polkadot-js to fail at reading the contract abi.

I've tried using the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) using the latest commit from master and also using the `v0.1.0` release. Same error in both cases.

```
> rustup info

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)
```

There are more details in an [issue on polkadot-js](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4151).

Any pointers on how to get a **working setup** would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was `substrate-contracts-node` using an [old version of the metadata](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/pull/8).

I was able to check out the repo before the metadata merge was reverted and build locally (`cargo build`).

So checkout [8d91b8e](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/commit/8d91b8e578065a7c06433cbd41ac059bf478a0bd) to get the node to work with versions `7.7.1` and `6.6.1` of polkadot-js packages.

```
> git checkout 8d91b8e578065a7c06433cbd41ac059bf478a0bd
> cargo build
> ./target/debug/substrate-contracts-node --dev --tmp --version
substrate-contracts-node 0.1.0-8d91b8e-x86_64-linux-gnu
```